# Custom EAV module doesn't insert entries to tables?

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, eav, table

I have created an EAV module. It has created below tables.

```
easyinnovates_carparks_carpark
easyinnovates_carparks_carpark_datetime
easyinnovates_carparks_carpark_decimal
easyinnovates_carparks_carpark_int
easyinnovates_carparks_carpark_text
easyinnovates_carparks_carpark_varchar
easyinnovates_carparks_eav_attribute
```

When I create an attribute it only saves in `eav_attribute` table. It doesn't insert it in the table `easyinnovates_carparks_eav_attribute`.

My controller file is as below.

```
<?php
class Easyinnovates_Carparks_Adminhtml_Carparks_Carpark_AttributeController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    protected $_entityTypeId;

    public function preDispatch() 
    {
        parent::preDispatch();
        $this->_entityTypeId = Mage::getModel('eav/entity')->setType(Easyinnovates_Carparks_Model_Carpark::ENTITY)->getTypeId();
    }

    protected function _initAction()
    {
        $this->_title(Mage::helper('easyinnovates_carparks')->__('Carpark'))
        ->_title(Mage::helper('easyinnovates_carparks')->__('Attributes'))
        ->_title(Mage::helper('easyinnovates_carparks')->__('Manage Attributes'));

        $this->loadLayout()
        ->_setActiveMenu('easyinnovates/carpark_attributes');
        return $this;
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->_initAction()
        ->renderLayout();
    }

    public function newAction()
    {
        $this->_forward('edit');
    }

    public function editAction()
    {
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('attribute_id');
        $model = Mage::getModel('easyinnovates_carparks/resource_eav_attribute')
        ->setEntityTypeId($this->_entityTypeId);
        if ($id) {
            $model->load($id);
            if (! $model->getId()) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(
                        Mage::helper('easyinnovates_carparks')->__('This carpark attribute no longer exists'));
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;
            }
            // entity type check
            if ($model->getEntityTypeId() != $this->_entityTypeId) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(
                        Mage::helper('easyinnovates_carparks')->__('This carpark attribute cannot be edited.'));
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;
            }
        }
        // set entered data if was error when we do save
        $data = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getAttributeData(true);
        if (! empty($data)) {
            $model->addData($data);
        }
        Mage::register('entity_attribute', $model);
        $this->_initAction();
        $this->_title($id ? $model->getName() : Mage::helper('easyinnovates_carparks')->__('New Carpark Attribute'));
        $item = $id ? Mage::helper('easyinnovates_carparks')->__('Edit Carpark Attribute')
        : Mage::helper('easyinnovates_carparks')->__('New Carpark Attribute');
        $this->_addBreadcrumb($item, $item);
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    public function validateAction()
    {
        $response = new Varien_Object();
        $response->setError(false);

        $attributeCode  = $this->getRequest()->getParam('attribute_code');
        $attributeId    = $this->getRequest()->getParam('attribute_id');
        $attribute = Mage::getModel('easyinnovates_carparks/attribute')
        ->loadByCode($this->_entityTypeId, $attributeCode);
        if ($attribute->getId() && !$attributeId) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(
                    Mage::helper('easyinnovates_carparks')->__('Attribute with the same code already exists'));
            $this->_initLayoutMessages('adminhtml/session');
            $response->setError(true);
            $response->setMessage($this->getLayout()->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml());
        }
        $this->getResponse()->setBody($response->toJson());
    }

    protected function _filterPostData($data)
    {
        if ($data) {
            $helper = Mage::helper('easyinnovates_carparks');
            //labels
            foreach ($data['frontend_label'] as & $value) {
                if ($value) {
                    $value = $helper->stripTags($value);
                }
            }
            //options
            if (!empty($data['option']['value'])) {
                foreach ($data['option']['value'] as &$options) {
                    foreach ($options as &$label) {
                        $label = $helper->stripTags($label);
                    }
                }
            }
            //default value
            if (!empty($data['default_value'])) {
                $data['default_value'] = $helper->stripTags($data['default_value']);
            }
            if (!empty($data['default_value_text'])) {
                $data['default_value_text'] = $helper->stripTags($data['default_value_text']);
            }
            if (!empty($data['default_value_textarea'])) {
                $data['default_value_textarea'] = $helper->stripTags($data['default_value_textarea']);
            }
        }
        return $data;
    }

    public function saveAction()
    {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        if ($data) {
            $session = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session');
            $redirectBack   = $this->getRequest()->getParam('back', false);
            $model = Mage::getModel('easyinnovates_carparks/resource_eav_attribute');
            $helper = Mage::helper('easyinnovates_carparks/carpark');
            $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('attribute_id');
            //validate attribute_code
            if (isset($data['attribute_code'])) {
                $validatorAttrCode = new Zend_Validate_Regex(array('pattern' => '/^[a-z_0-9]{1,255}$/'));
                if (!$validatorAttrCode->isValid($data['attribute_code'])) {
                    $session->addError(
                            Mage::helper('easyinnovates_carparks')->__('Attribute code is invalid. Please use only letters (a-z), numbers (0-9) or underscore(_) in this field, first character should be a letter.'));
                    $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('attribute_id' => $id, '_current' => true));
                    return;
                }
            }
            if ($id) {
                $model->load($id);
                if (!$model->getId()) {
                    $session->addError(
                            Mage::helper('easyinnovates_carparks')->__('This attribute no longer exists'));
                    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                    return;
                }

                // entity type check
                if ($model->getEntityTypeId() != $this->_entityTypeId) {
                    $session->addError(
                            Mage::helper('easyinnovates_carparks')->__('This attribute cannot be updated.'));
                    $session->setAttributeData($data);
                    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                    return;
                }

                $data['attribute_code'] = $model->getAttributeCode();
                $data['is_user_defined'] = $model->getIsUserDefined();
                $data['frontend_input'] = $model->getFrontendInput();
            } else {
                $data['source_model'] = $helper->getAttributeSourceModelByInputType($data['frontend_input']);
                $data['backend_model'] = $helper->getAttributeBackendModelByInputType($data['frontend_input']);
            }

            if (is_null($model->getIsUserDefined()) || $model->getIsUserDefined() != 0) {
                $data['backend_type'] = $model->getBackendTypeByInput($data['frontend_input']);
            }
            $defaultValueField = $model->getDefaultValueByInput($data['frontend_input']);
            if ($defaultValueField) {
                $data['default_value'] = $this->getRequest()->getParam($defaultValueField);
            }
            //filter
            $data = $this->_filterPostData($data);
            $model->addData($data);
            if (!$id) {
                $model->setEntityTypeId($this->_entityTypeId);
                $model->setIsUserDefined(1);
                $model->setIsVisible(1);
            }
            try {
                $model->save();
                $session->addSuccess(
                        Mage::helper('easyinnovates_carparks')->__('The carpark attribute has been saved.'));

                /**
                 * Clear translation cache because attribute labels are stored in translation
                */
                Mage::app()->cleanCache(array(Mage_Core_Model_Translate::CACHE_TAG));
                $session->setAttributeData(false);
                if ($redirectBack) {
                    $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('attribute_id' => $model->getId(),'_current'=>true));
                } else {
                    $this->_redirect('*/*/', array());
                }
                return;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $session->addError($e->getMessage());
                $session->setAttributeData($data);
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('attribute_id' => $id, '_current' => true));
                return;
            }
        }
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }
    public function deleteAction()
    {
        if ($id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('attribute_id')) {
            $model = Mage::getModel('easyinnovates_carparks/resource_eav_attribute');

            // entity type check
            $model->load($id);
            if ($model->getEntityTypeId() != $this->_entityTypeId) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(
                        Mage::helper('easyinnovates_carparks')->__('This attribute cannot be deleted.'));
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;
            }
            try {
                $model->delete();
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(
                        Mage::helper('easyinnovates_carparks')->__('The carpark attribute has been deleted.'));
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;
            }
            catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('attribute_id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('attribute_id')));
                return;
            }
        }
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(
                Mage::helper('easyinnovates_carparks')->__('Unable to find an attribute to delete.'));
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }

    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('cms/easyinnovates_carparks/carpark_attributes');
    }
}
```

My install script is as below.

```
<?php

$this->startSetup();

//create the entity table
$table = $this->getConnection()
                ->newTable($this->getTable('easyinnovates_carparks/carpark'))
                ->addColumn('entity_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
                        'identity'  => true,
                        'unsigned'  => true,
                        'nullable'  => false,
                        'primary'   => true,
                ), 'Entity ID')
                ->addColumn('entity_type_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
                        'unsigned'  => true,
                        'nullable'  => false,
                        'default'   => '0',
                ), 'Entity Type ID')
                ->addColumn('attribute_set_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
                        'unsigned'  => true,
                        'nullable'  => false,
                        'default'   => '0',
                ), 'Attribute Set ID')
                ->addColumn('created_at', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP, null, array(
                ), 'Creation Time')
                ->addColumn('updated_at', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP, null, array(
                ), 'Update Time')
                ->addIndex($this->getIdxName('easyinnovates_carparks/carpark', array('entity_type_id')),
                        array('entity_type_id'))
                        ->addIndex($this->getIdxName('easyinnovates_carparks/carpark', array('attribute_set_id')),
                                array('attribute_set_id'))
                                ->addForeignKey(
                                        $this->getFkName(
                                                'easyinnovates_carparks/carpark',
                                                'attribute_set_id',
                                                'eav/attribute_set',
                                                'attribute_set_id'
                                        ),
                                        'attribute_set_id', $this->getTable('eav/attribute_set'), 'attribute_set_id',
                                        Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE, Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE)
                                        ->addForeignKey($this->getFkName('easyinnovates_carparks/carpark', 'entity_type_id', 'eav/entity_type', 'entity_type_id'),
                                                'entity_type_id', $this->getTable('eav/entity_type'), 'entity_type_id',
                                                Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE, Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE)
                                                ->setComment('Carpark Table');
$this->getConnection()->createTable($table);

//create the attribute values tables (int, decimal, varchar, text, datetime)
$articleEav = array();
$articleEav['int'] = array(
        'type'      => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
        'length'    => null,
        'comment'   => 'Carpark Datetime Attribute Backend Table'
);

$articleEav['varchar'] = array(
        'type'      => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        'length'    => 255,
        'comment'   => 'Carpark Varchar Attribute Backend Table'
);

$articleEav['text'] = array(
        'type'      => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        'length'    => '64k',
        'comment'   => 'Carpark Text Attribute Backend Table'
);

$articleEav['datetime'] = array(
        'type'      => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_DATETIME,
        'length'    => null,
        'comment'   => 'Carpark Datetime Attribute Backend Table'
);

$articleEav['decimal'] = array(
        'type'      => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_DECIMAL,
        'length'    => '12,4',
        'comment'   => 'Carpark Datetime Attribute Backend Table'
);

foreach ($articleEav as $type => $options) {
    $table = $this->getConnection()
    ->newTable($this->getTable(array('easyinnovates_carparks/carpark', $type)))
    ->addColumn('value_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
            'identity'  => true,
            'nullable'  => false,
            'primary'   => true,
    ), 'Value ID')
    ->addColumn('entity_type_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
            'unsigned'  => true,
            'nullable'  => false,
            'default'   => '0',
    ), 'Entity Type ID')
    ->addColumn('attribute_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
            'unsigned'  => true,
            'nullable'  => false,
            'default'   => '0',
    ), 'Attribute ID')
    ->addColumn('store_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
            'unsigned'  => true,
            'nullable'  => false,
            'default'   => '0',
    ), 'Store ID')
    ->addColumn('entity_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
            'unsigned'  => true,
            'nullable'  => false,
            'default'   => '0',
    ), 'Entity ID')
    ->addColumn('value', $options['type'], $options['length'], array(
    ), 'Value')
    ->addIndex(
            $this->getIdxName(
                    array('easyinnovates_carparks/carpark', $type),
                    array('entity_id', 'attribute_id', 'store_id'),
                    Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::INDEX_TYPE_UNIQUE
            ),
            array('entity_id', 'attribute_id', 'store_id'),
            array('type' => Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::INDEX_TYPE_UNIQUE))
            ->addIndex($this->getIdxName(array('easyinnovates_carparks/carpark', $type), array('store_id')),
                    array('store_id'))
                    ->addIndex($this->getIdxName(array('easyinnovates_carparks/carpark', $type), array('entity_id')),
                            array('entity_id'))
                            ->addIndex($this->getIdxName(array('easyinnovates_carparks/carpark', $type), array('attribute_id')),
                                    array('attribute_id'))
                                    ->addForeignKey(
                                            $this->getFkName(
                                                    array('easyinnovates_carparks/carpark', $type),
                                                    'attribute_id',
                                                    'eav/attribute',
                                                    'attribute_id'
                                            ),
                                            'attribute_id', $this->getTable('eav/attribute'), 'attribute_id',
                                            Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE, Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE)
                                            ->addForeignKey(
                                                    $this->getFkName(
                                                            array('easyinnovates_carparks/carpark', $type),
                                                            'entity_id',
                                                            'easyinnovates_carparks/carpark',
                                                            'entity_id'
                                                    ),
                                                    'entity_id', $this->getTable('easyinnovates_carparks/carpark'), 'entity_id',
                                                    Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE, Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE)
                                                    ->addForeignKey($this->getFkName(array('easyinnovates_carparks/carpark', $type), 'store_id', 'core/store', 'store_id'),
                                                            'store_id', $this->getTable('core/store'), 'store_id',
                                                            Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE, Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE)
                                                            ->setComment($options['comment']);
    $this->getConnection()->createTable($table);
}
//crete the carparks_eav_attribute (for additional attribute settings)
$table = $this->getConnection()
            ->newTable($this->getTable('easyinnovates_carparks/eav_attribute'))
            ->addColumn('attribute_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
                    'identity'  => true,
                    'nullable'  => false,
                    'primary'   => true,
            ), 'Attribute ID')
            ->addColumn('is_global', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(), 'Attribute scope')
            ->addColumn('position', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(), 'Attribute position')
            ->addColumn('is_wysiwyg_enabled', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(), 'Attribute uses WYSIWYG')
            ->addColumn('is_visible', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(), 'Attribute is visible')
            ->setComment('Carparks attribute table');

$this->getConnection()->createTable($table);

$this->installEntities();
$this->endSetup();
```

Can anyone figure out what am I missing here?

Comment: Do you have your own setup class where `getDefaultEntities` includes information about the `additional_attribute_table` etc?

Answer (score 0):

As Peter O'Callaghan mentions in the comments, the additional attribute table is not going to be recognized automatically, you need to specify that it is used and what the fields are. By default EAV attributes do **not** use an additional table.

Have a look at `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup::getDefaultEntities()` to see how it works.